# asp: Gridview footer row on top of items?

Tags: asp.net

i'm sorry for this dumb question but is there any way to display the gridview footer row just below the header and above the gridview rows?

i've tried using css:

```
position: absolute;
top: 82px;
width: 44%;
```

and it worked,

ISSUE:

if i have more than one gridview on the page,
Gridview1 is above Gridview2. 
the page will be messed up because of the position: absolute;

Is there a way to display the footer just below the header without using my css code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different CSS class for each GridView - each with it's own position values.

However, using absolute position for the footer of each GridView sounds quite brittle.

I think a better solution would be to put the relevant information in the header - where it sounds like it should be.

If you use `<asp:TemplateField>` and `<HeaderTemplate>` you can get quite a lot of control on what's in the header.

Comment: hmmm.. currently i'm using both TemplateField and HeaderTemplate, also FooterTemplate @joer

Comment: Can you not get everything you need in the Header? Otherwise, a separate CSS class may be the only option...